# Political message of Hindemith's "Der Schwanendreher"

Tags: history

Hindemith composed this acclaimed viola concerto right around the time when the Nazis came to power and began attacking his works. Since he composed this concerto during such a stressful period, I was wondering if there is a political message within the work, targetted at the Nazis?

Comment: At least according to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Schwanendreher, it has no political message what-so-ever, but all of it was supposedly based on German folk songs.